# Removing one person's comments but not removing the response addressed to them?

Tags: discussion

RE: This thread, "[Are there any Protestant denominations that reject penal substitution?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/48549/20)"

I'd like to see this site be fair and unbiased in regards to its posters but it's not. My comments were deleted as being discussion, not clarification (I suppose I could reword them) but DJ Clayworth's comment to me was not deleted. It makes sense to keep his comment posted if he's speaking to someone but he's not; mine were deleted.

If mine are going to be deleted, then isn't it fair to remove DJ Clayworth's comments as well since mine are gone and his are speaking to nobody?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right.  That was my personal oversight.  It should now be corrected  Thanks for bringing it up.

Often the community intends to flag a chain of comments as "too chatty" or "obsolete".  Since there's no way to flag an entire chain at once, they sometimes flag all the comments, or they flag just one and rely on the moderators to understand that there are several comments that need to be deleted.  In this case, only one comment was flagged, and I didn't spot the other related ones, so i just deleted the flagged one.

If you so desire, in the future, you can also bring it up by flagging the other comments that need to be deleted.